# Invoke background remote job

Tags: powershell

I have a problem with start-job and invoke-command. When I run it locally it works as it should, but when I use it remotely it just exists and does nothing. This is the command:

invoke-command {start-job { & notepad}}

Notepad is just an example, as I want another process to run in the background. How to fix it to work remotely? It seems like an issue with powershell session closing after invoke-command. On Linux it was fixed by using nohup command but I can't find anything that would resemble it in powershell.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this, from the local system:

```
invoke-command -scriptblock { & notepad } -computername <remote computer> -asjob
```

Comment: I've tried this already, but it doesn't work. It seems as it can't be done as it looks like invoke-command is creating a session and then killing it immediately after execution.

Comment: It will kill the remote session if you end the local PS session after you run invoke-command.  If you're wanting to start a job, disconnnect the session and re-connect later, you'll need to use a persistent job (requires V3).

Comment: Ok I've managed to find a way around it by using schtasks, thanks anyway.